# How to generate multiline graphs from csv data with timestamp as x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Below is my sample data in CSV format (`stats_1.csv`):

```
timestamp,ip,CPU,memory
2017-08-24 18:57:40,10.20.6.181,46,14
2017-08-24 18:57:50,10.20.6.182,43,12
2017-08-24 19:07:40,10.20.6.181,46,14
2017-08-24 19:07:50,10.20.6.182,43,12
2017-08-24 19:17:40,10.20.6.181,46,14
2017-08-24 19:17:50,10.20.6.182,43,12
2017-08-24 19:27:40,10.20.6.181,46,14
2017-08-24 19:27:50,10.20.6.182,43,12
2017-08-24 19:37:40,10.20.6.181,46,14
2017-08-24 18:37:50,10.20.6.182,43,12
```

I want to have 2D line graphs from this with X-axis as time stamp and Y-axis as 
CPU (there will be a separate graph for memory).

In the graph, there should be one line for each IP and legends.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

# setup the dataframe
data_frame = pandas.read_csv("stats_1.csv")

def plot_cpu_utilization_graphs(df):
    column_name = 'CPU'
    df = df[[column_name, 'timestamp', 'ip']]
    max_value = df[column_name].max()
    if max_value < 100:
        max_value = 100
    min_value = df[column_name].min()
    if min_value > 0:
        min_value = 0
    start_idx = df['timestamp'].iloc[0]
    end_idx = df['timestamp'].iloc[-1]
    time_series = pandas.DatetimeIndex(freq='10T', start=start_idx, end=end_idx)
    y_axes_series = range(min_value, max_value, 10)
    #ax = df.groupby('ip').plot(x='timestamp', y='CPU')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    df.groupby("ip").plot(x='timestamp', y='CPU', ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlim(time_series[0], time_series[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(min_value, max_value)
    plt.show()



plot_cpu_utilization_graphs(data_frame)
```

And this is what I am getting: [image]

Comment: The first time in the df is `18:57`, the last is `18:37`, meaning that end is earlier than start, hence you would get an empty `time_series`. Apart from that it also might make sense to parse the timestamp column as dates, ie. `pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates=[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your timestamp column to datetime format, then it should work:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```